# Is it ok to pass OAuth access tokens to the Client

Tags: reactjs, authentication, server, oauth

i'm still pretty new to web-development I worked myself through **Web Development with Node and Express** by *Ethan Brown* and currently i'm trying to get a good understanding for the examples given by **Full-Stack React Projects** by *Shama Hoque*.

Currently i'm trying to refactor a lot of things that used to be server-side-rendered to be handled in the React SPA client. One of these things includes a simple GitHub widget, my previous flow worked like this:

1. The client user authenticates with my server using a GitHub OAuth app.
2. The server stores the access Token returned to the callback in a database on the **server**.
3. The **server** makes calls to the GitHub API using the user access Token stored in the database.
4. The **server** processes the results, renders it in HTML and sends it to the client.

However I realized that there is also possibility to implement it like this.

1. The client user authenticates with my server using a GitHub OAuth app.
2. The server passes the access Token returned to the callback back to the **client**
3. The **client** makes calls to the GitHub API using the user access token obtained from the server.
4. The **client** processes the results and renders it apropiately.

As far as I understand there is no inherent security risk doing this(a malacious user could interecept the access token when the oAuth provider redirects to the callback either way) and both flows have their up and downsides (e.g. 2nd flow produces less load on the server but also sacrifices control). Since I'm new to this and I came up with the 2nd flow myself I wanna double check if this is something thats ok to be doing or I've missed something, if so, what did I miss? Is there any other major down or upsides i'm not considering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've implemented is the [OAuth Authorization Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code).  In this flow, the client (aka the browser) *never* gets the access token.  Only your webserver gets it.  And thus the client cannot make calls to the resource server (github).  Your webserver makes the calls on the client's behalf.

You say:

> a malacious user could interecept the access token when the oAuth provider redirects to the callback either way

However, if you implement the flow correctly, this is not true.  This is because once you authenticate with the resource server, it only gives the browser an authentication *code*.  This *code* is just a temporary ticket that can be exchanged for an access token.  However, to exchange a code for the access token, you have to know a client secret.  Only your web server knows the secret.  So your browser sends the code to your server, and your server calls the resource server (github) with the code + secret to get the token.

The second flow you describe is the [OAuth Implicit Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/implicit).

This flow is very much what you described:  After the user authenticates with the resource server, the browser ends up with the access token and just calls the resource server directly.

Both flows are very common.  The Implicit flow is slightly less secure because there is more opportunity for Bad Guys to get access to the token in the browser's memory (or local storage, or cookie storage).  The Authorization Flow is a bit more secure because the token stays on your server, and you do not have to depend upon users to keep it secure.

Comment: _However, if you implement the flow correctly, this is not true. This is because once you authenticate with the resource server, it only gives the browser an authentication code_ I knew I should have implemented the OAuth Flow completely from scratch for the first time around instead of just using passport.js, if i did that I wouldn't have missed that, maybe i'm going back to do that. Thanks alot for your elaborate answer.