# OAuth2 - Returning access/refresh tokens to end-user in Authorization code flow

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, oauth

Using the authorization code flow, a confidential client (web server for example) ends up with an access token and a refresh token. Now, let's assume that the web server decides to return these tokens to the end-user directly (example: browser). From what I've read, this is generally considered bad practice, but I am unable to find out exactly why.

I've read various similar questions, but none of the answers really satisfy me and I believe there might be something I'm misundertanding.

- [OAuth2 - Is it safe to return the access-token to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880489/oauth2-is-it-safe-to-return-the-access-token-to-the-user)

> An access token is supposed to be short living, it usually expires in a few minutes. Unless the client fetches the data immediately, it's no use. Refresh tokens are used as permanent grants, but you should never ever share them unless you intentionally want to screw up your server security.

But isn't this also true of Authorization Code Flow with PKCE, which as far as I'm aware is considered secure? What is the difference in security between using the Authorization Code Flow and returning the tokens to the end user vs using the Authorization Code Flow With PKCE where the end user will also end up with the tokens?

- [Is it ok to pass OAuth access tokens to the Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571552/is-it-ok-to-pass-oauth-access-tokens-to-the-client)

This one assumes the alternative is to use the implicit flow, but this isn't what I'm talking about. My scenario is a confidential app that uses the Authorization Code Flow and then returns the tokens to the end user rather than the implicit flow which doesn't use a client secret.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things here. Firstly, the most secure [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) way to run a code flow is to use PKCE and a client secret, along with `response_type=code`, so that no tokens are received in browser responses.

Secondly, a best practice for browser based apps is to use a [backend for frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) that issues secure HTTP only cookies, to keep tokens out of the browser.

The main browser concern is usually cross site scripting, and potentially unpredictable threats in the browser, that could intercept and exfiltrate tokens. There are some mitigations against such threats, but stakeholders are likely to prefer the more established cookie solution.

A good way to think about it is if you had to get on the phone and explain your security to an important customer, eg a bank. In this case, the conversation is easier if you can say your solution is based on a best practices doc, such as that above.